# Getting mail room calendar in Lotus Domino

Tags: lotus-domino, interop-domino

We are trying to integrate the Lotus Domino with our application.
We are looking for the following operations :
1) Get the availability of the mail room between certain time interval.
2) Booking a Mail room.

Is there any way i can do that.I know there is a REST service exposed by IBM domino,but that is not helping much in the mail room booking and getting of the calendar.

Comment: What version of Domino?  There is a REST freebusy API available for Domino 9.0.1 (see the extlib project on OpenNTF).  That would let you check the availability of a room.  Also, Domino 9.0.1 includes a REST calendar API.  That would let you book a room.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but it might give you some ideas or lead you in the right direction.

If your Domino server is running HTTP you can create an agent (or an xagent) that you put in a Domino database on 
server that do what you need, you can program the agent or xagent to output anything you need, json, xml or what ever.

you can then read the output from the agent/xagent from your app using an url /mydb/myagent?openagent or /mydb/myxagent.xsp

If you need to book a room or find available times for a room, take a look in the design of the resource and reservation database, it contains all the code you need as this database already do it.